# twitter integration on android app

Tags: android, twitter

I would like to integrate Twitter into my Android application so that I can post messages to Twitter.

Comment: this is as simple as eating your favourite cake.. follow this tutorial http://tech-papers.org/integrate-twitter-with-android-application/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to d.'s solid choices, you could:

- Use `ACTION_SEND` `Intents` with `createChooser()`, and if the user has a Twitter application installed (Twidroid) they can use it to update their status
- Use an existing Twitter Java API, like JTwitter

Comment: I checked it out just to see how you did the integration and I ended up downloading. Great job!

Comment: `ACTION_SEND` is too vague. Gmail and dropbox are eligible. [I suggest you filter](http://regis.decamps.info/blog/2011/06/intent-to-open-twitter-client-on-android/) the list based on known package names.

Comment: Deleted a comment, updated details: I don't use JTwitter in my Android app any more (and the Twitter API and Terms has entirely changed since then, making direct integration more challenging). 

The source code for the app I made that used to do this, Congress, has also moved, to: github.com/sunlightlabs/congress-android -- but it no longer has direct Twitter integration.

Answer (score 20):

This is how I do it

First i made a Dialog for the webview 
Twitter_Dialog.java

```
public class Twitter_Dialog extends Dialog
{

static final int                      BLUE                  = 0xFF6D84B4;
static final float[]                  DIMENSIONS_DIFF_LANDSCAPE =
                                                                { 20, 60 };
static final float[]                  DIMENSIONS_DIFF_PORTRAIT  =
                                                                { 40, 60 };
static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams   FILL                    = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
static final int                      MARGIN                    = 4;
static final int                      PADDING                   = 2;
static final String                   DISPLAY_STRING            = "touch";

private String                        mUrl;
private ProgressDialog                mSpinner;
private WebView                       mWebView;
private LinearLayout                  mContent;
private TextView                      mTitle;

public Twitter_Dialog(Context context, String url)
{
    super(context);
    mUrl = url;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mSpinner.setMessage("Loading...");

    mContent = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    mContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setUpTitle();
    setUpWebView();
    Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int orientation = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    float[] dimensions = (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) ? DIMENSIONS_DIFF_LANDSCAPE : DIMENSIONS_DIFF_PORTRAIT;
    addContentView(mContent, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(display.getWidth() - ((int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f)), display.getHeight() - ((int) (dimensions[1] * scale + 0.5f))));
}

private void setUpTitle()
{
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Drawable icon = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twitter_icon);
    mTitle = new TextView(getContext());
    mTitle.setText("Website");
    mTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    mTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    mTitle.setBackgroundColor(BLUE);
    mTitle.setPadding(MARGIN + PADDING, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
    mTitle.setCompoundDrawablePadding(MARGIN + PADDING);
    mTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);
    mContent.addView(mTitle);
}

private void setUpWebView()
{
    mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new Twitter_Dialog.DialogWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    System.out.println(" mURL = "+mUrl);

    mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
    mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
    mContent.addView(mWebView);
}

private class DialogWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
    {
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        Twitter_Dialog.this.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        mSpinner.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        String title = mWebView.getTitle();
        if (title != null && title.length() > 0){
            mTitle.setText(title);
            if(title.equals("Twitter")){
                //This will close the Dialog after tweeting
                Twitter_Dialog.this.dismiss();

            }
        }
        mSpinner.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

//And then into your Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            new Twitter_Dialog(Main.this,"http://twitter.com/?status="+Uri.encode("Twitter Post")).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: excellent code but can u tell me how to post image using this code

Comment: how can twitte my message(my game score) on twitter .

Comment: How i cant post massage on twitter  click  on button

Answer (score 4):

Everything you need to know about communicating with Twitter is [here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/).

For sending HTTP requests from your application, check out [this guide](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010011/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Twitter Helper](https://github.com/krazykira/Twitter-Helper) for integrating Twitter into your Android app. Its very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this simple client [TwitterEasyClient](https://github.com/simoarpe/TwitterEasyClient)

Just add permissions in your manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And use it in this way:

```
    //setup
    TwitterDialogFragment twitterDialog = new TwitterDialogFragment.Builder("message","url.com") //
    .callbackUrl("http://www.website.com") //
    .consumerKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") //
    .consumerSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") //
    .urlOAuth("oauth_verifier") //
    .build();

    //show the dialog
    twitterDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TwitterDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Always go for the latest technologies as twitter integration can be done easily using Twitter4j, also the APIs provided by twitter does change from time to time. Twiter sdk would a good option. [U can find the details for it here for twitter4j.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626932/using-twitter4j-for-integration-to-tweet-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

For some people who want to use twitter4j and DialogFragment also support orientation changing check out my gist
https://gist.github.com/zeroarst/10071064adcf171277f9