# Android connecting to Twitter

Tags: android, upload, twitter

I'm learning Android and I'm trying to connect to Twitter and upload a photo in Android.  How can I do this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming site :)

Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: I think he want to do this with code. And then this is the right page. But the questions is very very broad and hard to answer in an easy way.

Comment: Twitter doesn't support photos by itself, so you will need to use another place to upload the photos such as twitpic. Or you can just start an intent to another twitter program, such as twitroid which can do the complicated twitter stuff for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [twitter integration on android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app)

Answer (score 2):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application) gives you a hint on how to use an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to start a Twitter application and use it to to post something. In this way the user don't have to give your program the twitter credentials.

If you want to connect to twitter yourself you can use one of the [java twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#java) apis that are out there.

I hope this is a starting point. If you encounter more specific problems come back and we will be glad to answer them.

For a general howto on Android check out the [hello world](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) application and all the other tutorials on the android developer pages.

Comment: Thanks for the information, is any sample code to using java twitter api?