# Twitter Application-android

Tags: twitter

1.Can anyone explain the concept of TweetDeck Application in twitter
2.How to implement new application in twitter in android

Comment: possible duplicate of [twitter integration on android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app)

Answer (score 1):

TweetDeck is a tool for giving better overview of Twitter activity. You can set up multiple accounts to easily switch between when posting, you can create any number of columns listing posts based on a variety of criteria: posts from any given user, or all posts that mention @you, or the real time results for a given search query, say.

As for your #2, this question has been asked before. [Perhaps you can find your answer here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app)

Comment: can you please tell me how to make reply for the tweets and methods used to implement -Thank u