# Twitter Integration in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [twitter integration on android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app)

How can I integrate Twitter with my Android application?

Comment: See [
twitter integration on android app
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app) among others.

Comment: hi Matthew,thnx for reply.. bt here i m not getting any help.. Can u pls explain these things. pls

Comment: Hi Shubh you should try to increase the rate of accepted answers. If somebody solved one of your problems you can mark the correct answer by clicking on the green checkmark near the left side of the question. This will give you and the person helping you some reputation and shows that you try to do your part in the stackoverflow community.

Comment: I used old one but that one not working so i asked here again .from where i got that new API for Twitter. pls suggest. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about starting with some tutorials about using Twitter API, such as [Twitter Access in Java](http://merlinsource.blogspot.com/2008/11/twitter-access-in-java.html)

Comment: thanx Fernando Miguélez fro reply, I use this one also but my android app not working. Force Close occur. pls suggest me any other way.

Comment: There may be some classes not supported directly on Android. Have you tracked the errors? Other way could be implementing your own API since Twitter has a REST API (by means of httpclient)

Comment: thnx again for reply, i will inform u shortly.