# Android twitter post

Tags: android

Where to find complete tutorial for posting twitter status from android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[twitter integration on android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app) i hope this will be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Use [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html). A java library for Twitter that works in Android.