# Post Pictures to Twitter in Android

Tags: android

Hello I want to make an app that post a specific picture to users twitter account. To make this i think i must ask user his/her twitter username and password. I use twitter4j to make this but i cannot figure how to do it. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: see this post:[android-twitter-post)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227665/android-twitter-post)...

Comment: i need to post picture not just text. i can post text but no picture.

Comment: hi Mert,see my post may be helpful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this using **twitter4j**:

```
 String  content = et_content.getText().toString();
    String  describle = et_des.getText().toString();
String result = "";
            ConfigurationBuilder confBuild = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            confBuild.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONST.CONSUMER_KEY);
            confBuild.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONST.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            confBuild.setOAuthAccessToken(spf.getString("oauth_token", ""));
            confBuild.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(spf.getString(
                    "oauth_token_secret", ""));
            twitter4j.conf.Configuration config = confBuild.build();
            if (TwitterConnect.twitter != null)
                TwitterConnect.twitter.shutdown();
        TwitterConnect.twitter =new TwitterFactory(config).getInstance();
        InputStream input =null;
        try {
        TwitterConnect.accessToken = TwitterConnect.twitter
        .getOAuthAccessToken();
        boolean bTest =false;
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        try {
        input = am.open("toukou.png");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (tc ==null) {
        tc =new TwitterConnect(Twitter.this);
        }
        bTest = tc.TwitterContribute(content, input, describle);

        if (bTest) {
        result ="ok";
        } else {
        result ="failure";
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return result;
        }
```

Comment: what is the  TwitterConnect class if u have post the complete code

Comment: I'm guessing that the key part is in TwitterContribute, what is this?