# Uploading image to twitter using twitter api in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to post image to twitter using twitter api?

If possible how to do,please provide some information on this.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post Pictures to Twitter in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724142/post-pictures-to-twitter-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You need the Twitter4J Library for Sharing Pic and that should be latest one can be taken from [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)

and can use the following method to post Image

```
    **
 * To upload a picture with some piece of text.
 * 
 * 
 * @param file The file which we want to share with our tweet
 * @param message Message to display with picture
 * @param twitter Instance of authorized Twitter class
 * @throws Exception exception if any
 */

public void uploadPic(File file, String message,Twitter twitter) throws Exception  {
    try{
        StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(message);
        status.setMedia(file);
        twitter.updateStatus(status);}
    catch(TwitterException e){
        Log.d("TAG", "Pic Upload error" + e.getErrorMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [Android Demo](https://github.com/itog/Twitter4j-android-Sample). May it Helps.

```
if(isConnected()){
    OAuthService authService = new ServiceBuilder()
                                .provider(TwitterApi.class)
                                .apiKey(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY)
                                .apiSecret(Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET)
                                .callback(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL)
                                .build();
    final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json");
                verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(Constants.IEXTRA_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                try {   
                    Token token = getToken();
                    if(token!=null){
                        authService.signRequest(token, request); 
                        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

                        entity.addPart("status", new StringBody("Your Status!"));       // THIS IS THE TWITTER MESSAGE
                        entity.addPart("media", new FileBody(new File(uriString)));  // THIS IS THE PHOTO TO UPLOAD

                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        entity.writeTo(out);

                        request.addPayload(out.toByteArray());
                        request.addHeader(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,Constants.LABEL_BLANK, "Uploading Image",true);
                Thread requestThread = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            response = new JSONObject (request.send().getBody());
                            uiHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                        }catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("TOUR_APP_TAG", "JSONException Thrown: " + e.getMessage());
                            errorHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                        }
                    }
                };
                requestThread.start();
}
...
...
final Handler uiHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(progressDialog != null)progressDialog.dismiss();
        if(response.has("id"))
            //your code
    }
};

final Handler errorHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(progressDialog != null)progressDialog.dismiss();
            //your code
    }
};
```