# using twitter4j for integration to tweet in android

Tags: android, twitter4j

please tell me where can i find twitter4j sdk for android and at least one example how to implement log-in and tweet in android application.

I have searched but not found the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of how to login and tweet using OAuth:
http://blog.blundellapps.com/sending-a-tweet/

Comment: error in android 5.1 nexus 4 url scheme not found on device

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a "for Android" SDK per say, but the normal Twitter4J SDK should work just fine according to their site: http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#download
There are code examples on the site as well: http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html