# how to post tweets from android application

Tags: android, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [twitter integration on android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app)

Hi all, how to post the tweets from my android application. I searched stackoverflow for this but i failed to get the solution. can anyone tell me how can i proceed now??

thanks
venu

Comment: This question is equals your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can e.g. use twitter4j ( http://twitter4j.org/ ) to do this.
Have a look at http://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA for an Android Twitter client that uses this library.

In earlier days it was easier to access Twitter, but nowadays you need to implement oAuth to connecto to Twitter.

An alternative could be to create an account at http://identi.ca/ , post to this account and have identi.ca forward your messages to Twitter.

Comment: @Heiko Rupp, really very very thanks for your app. It is really awesome. i installed your .apk file and it is working as i am expecting, downloaded your source code, created 'TwitterConsumerToken' class and my consumerKey="hN5Imz3gMiIHYtGmeWKRQ"
consumerSecret = "QIsNoUc7HL0WNKg7y5Ql1fg0Uf4cPcyyevscmllJG0". when i run your code with these values i am not getting that PIN code, instead it is redirecting to my website. What mistake i made when registering the app in twitter?? can you explain me??

Comment: This is strange when it redirects to your homepage - perhaps some router that rewrites http requests?

Comment: i have reistered another app, got consumerKey="ComtNJ0ENl2kwS0arx5g" and consumerSecret="SeJeLMYxV5v3qciinzLwYMGmhJxiZHIC4ccVmyiZAH0", got Pin also.  But the problem is after entering Pin into your app it is get crashed with NullPointerException at  de.bsd.zwitscher.TabWidget.onCreate(TabWidget.java:57). For this application registration i set the Application Type as Client. Are there any mistakes in my approach?? can you guide me?

Comment: I fear that may be with the recent code - I may not have updated the new multi account handling to the classic oAuth. Try to checkout the v065 tag and retry. And open an issue on GitHub, so that I don't forget to fix the oAuth case. Thanks

Comment: sure!! can you just tell me onething what would be the Application Type(Client/Browser) when we registering the application in twitter??

Comment: I've registered Zwitscher as Client