# Post to Twitter in Android

Tags: java, android, twitter

What is the preferred way to post something to your Twitter?

Earlier you could use:

```
Twitter twitter = new Twitter(username, password);
twitter.updateStatus("Ohai, I can haz cheeseburger?!");
```

However, that doesn't work now. What is the alternative way?

Comment: "earlier"? really? Did you mean "ideally"?

Comment: I've read that you cannot do it this way anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [twitter integration on android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the twitter4j API:

http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

And here is an O'reilly tutorial with sample code:

http://creativelive.com/courses/developing-android-applications-java-part-1-partnership-oreilly

Comment: And here's a reason why you might wish to write another app instead: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-12731343

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed before: [twitter integration on android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app)