# How Do i integrate Twitter in my Android application?

Tags: android, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [twitter integration on android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app)

Someone please help me how to integrate twitter in my android application. any example using twittter framework like Jtwitter would be helpful.
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/69.html
Great example right there. Also, we are working on an open sourced twitter library over at T3hh4xx0r if your interested in the API code itself. https://github.com/T3hh4xx0r/libJTwitter