# Android Twitter integration - stuck in the sign in page?

Tags: android, twitter, android-webview, android-twitter

I have code from a previous Android app which I successfully integrated with Twitter. I've copied this code over to a new app and changed the `callback-url`, `consumer-key` and `consumer-secret` for my new app.

Using the `twitter4j` library I'm able to get my `RequestToken` and authentication url as follows:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(myConsumerKey, myConsumerSecret);
RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(myCallbackUrl);
String authenticationUrl = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL()
```

The `RequestToken` has a non-null `token` value, a non-null `tokenSecret` value, and a null `secretKeySpec` value. The authentication url is of the following form:

```
http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=...
```

I load this url in my `WebView` and I see the following page:

[image: Sign in page]

Here I'm stuck. When I click the `Sign In` button, just this same page keeps loading up. Nothing else. When I click the `Cancel` button however, I see the following page:

[image]

Only on this page when I click the `Return to Fan League Beko BBL` button is my `callback-url` invoked, with a `denied` parameter which has my `oauth_token` as its value. Anyone seen anything like this before and know what might be stopping my sign in request from being processed???

> **Update 1:** I've tried the authentication url and the `Sign In` button from a desktop browser and it works as expected, processing the response and then invoking the callback-url. It's just failing when trying it in the `WebView` of my Android app. I've tried it on multiple Android devices and tablets. JavaScript is enabled on my `WebView` too so that's not it. Ideas most welcome. I'm out of ideas!
>
> **Update 2:** I've just done some debug-mode code-tracing on my `WebView`'s `WebViewClient` and I'm seeing that when I click the `Sign In` button, the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)` method is not called, but the following three methods are called (in order): `onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)`, `onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)`, `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)`. The `url` value these methods have is: `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate`, i.e. the `oauth_token` parameter has been stripped off the authenticate url. Maybe this is a `POST` request being treated as a `GET` request and hence why this one same page keeps loading up? Any ideas what I can do to have this `Sign In` button press processed properly?

Comment: Hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app/12417449#12417449

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely my Twitter integration has started working. I didn't change my application code or my application's Twitter settings. I've noticed that where the Twitter authenticate page had a blue `Sign In` button previously, it now has a blue `Authenticate app` button. So I'm guessing something was changed/fixed on Twitter's end.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you forgot to set a callback url from twitter app control panel.

Log into twitter api section, choose your app and go to settings tab.

[image]

If you don't, when the user press login no redirect will happen and thus you will not be able to catch the verifier.

When you set a callback url on the other hand, your webview can intercept the redirect.

NOTE: You can set whatever url you want, the important thing is to catch the oauth_verifier parameter passed to the redirect url.

In that case your

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading
```

should be triggered.

Comment: I double-checked and there's definitely a callback-url specified. The callback-url is being called (with a `denied` parameter) when I hit the `Cancel` and then the `Return to Fan League Beko BBL` button.

Answer (score 1):

Override `onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)` from WebViewClient and use this code inside Authorization Activity where you use `webView.loadUrl(authenticationUrl)` in onResume() and `webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient)` in onCreate().

```
private WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        // the URL we're looking for looks like this:
        // callbackurl?oauth_token=1234567890qwertyuiop
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        if (uri.getHost().equals("callbackurlhost")) {
            String token = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
            if (null != token) {
                webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
                // TODO store access token
                finish();
            } else {
                // TODO tell user to try again 
            }
        } else {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: When I click the `Sign In` button, the `url` value passed into the `onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)` method is `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate` (with no `oauth_token` parameter) and not that of my callback-url.

Comment: Actually your callback-url will be called after logging in and being redirected and in onLoadResource() you will be notified when this event happens. Also make sure that when you are registering new applications on twitter website, Application Type is Browser not Client.

Answer (score 1):

I have integrated sharing on twitter in my application recently. Its working perfectly.

I have used latest twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar

I have created a simple demo application, you can download it from following links and go thorugh it.
http://santhoshkumaar.blogspot.in/2013/02/posting-message-on-twitter.html
https://github.com/santhoshkumaar/ShareOnTwitter/

This might be helpful to you.

Comment: What's the `twitter4j-media-support-3.0.3` jar for?

Comment: twitter4j-media-support-3.0.3 jar for multimedia support like uploading images etc. You can ignore this.

Comment: thanqqqqq sooooo muchhhhhhh

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the callback url?

**public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "twitterapp://connect";**

check your authorize method:

```
mHttpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey, mSecretKey);
mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                                                     "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                                                     "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

public void authorize() 
{
        mProgressDlg.setMessage("Initializing ...");
        mProgressDlg.show();

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String authUrl = "";
                int what = 1;

                try {
                    authUrl = mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(mHttpOauthConsumer, CALLBACK_URL);    

                    what = 0;

                    Log.d(TAG, "Request token url " + authUrl);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to get request token");

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 1, 0, authUrl));
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

**make call to twitter.authorize();**
Hope this helps

Comment: I've specified a callback-url. That's not the problem.